# Storing list in mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, list

Each row on my mysql table represents a different item.
Each item has a attribute `used_by_classes` which can be a list with more than one element and up to 9, such as `"Scout,Spy,Pyro"`

I wonder what is the overall best way to store that information.

I was storing it as a list like above on a table `used_by_classes` and exploding it with php.

```
$classes= explode(",", $used_by_classes);
```

But thats just unreliable and probably silly. Creating 9 separate columns is another alternative but complicates things further on. How would you deal with this ?

Comment: Create a separate table and use a parent_id, used_by_class and store them keyed to the parent id.

Comment: May I suggest you brush up on Normal forms?
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/third-normal-form.htm

Answer (score 1):

For multi-valued attributes, the normative pattern is to create a second table. Each row in the new table will store one value of the attribute.

If the first table is

```
item (id int unsigned primary key, ...)
```

The second table would be something like:

```
item_class
( id            INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
, item_id       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref item.id'
, used_by_class VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
```

We'd likely add a unique constraint on the `(item_id, used_by_class)` tuple. With InnoDB, we'd create a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint referencing the item table.

```
item
 id name 
--- -----
 11 Cake

item_class
 id item_id used_by_class
--- ------- ------------- 
412      11 Scout
413      11 Spy
414      11 Pyro
415      11 Demoman
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also serialize that data at store them. and when when you fetch the record you can un-serialize them all.

```
item
id  name   used_by_class
--- ----- ---------------
11  Cake   {scout:Spy:pyro}
```

similar like this